# IIS7 Error: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, unicode

I have a problem when a url contains Chinese characters. It doesn't happen every time, but when it does, I find the following errors in the event log:

```
EventMessage
    No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070459) 
EventStackTrace
    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070459)
    at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
    at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariableInternal(String name)
    at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariable(String name)
    at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ReadRequestHeaders()
    at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetKnownRequestHeader(Int32 index)
    at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInHeadersCollection()
    at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Headers()
```

It seems the exception was thrown in the native method.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this happens when a Cookie or other header contains a unicode character. This [blog entry](http://blogs.iis.net/yigalatz/archive/2010/11/24/replacing-the-built-in-basic-authentication-module-to-support-non-english-characters-in-a-httpwebrequest.aspx) may shed some light on the problem and a solution.

Comment: +1. Including non-ASCII characters in cookies is wildly unreliable across different browsers and servers. Always encode to some 7-bit-safe format (eg URL-encode cookie values).

Comment: Thanks, the link might come from out our side. We always encode url because the unicode characters, it never happen when we use II6

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by send data as `Base64String`, in my case it is an object:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Json.Convert(myObject))
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("data" , Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
```